# Display 3 divs in same line (Image Gallery+Text+Webform)

Tags: css, webforms, bootstrap-4, drupal-8, drupal-views

I'm trying to display 3 divs in the same line. Developing in Drupal8 Bootstrap Theme (working on Subtheme). These Divs are fields inside a view called viewproducts.

The divs are as follows:

1. Juicebox Photo Gallery;
2. Text: `"Title"+"Reference Label:" & "Reference number"+ "Description" + "Price Label" & "Price";`
3. Webform: `"First and Last Name"+ "Email" + "Phone" + "Message" + "Send Button"`

The idea is to have products rows, each row being formed by the elements described above in the following order in the screen:

```
LEFT: Juicebox Gallery          CENTER: Text group of elements          RIGHT: Webform
```

Gallery=Ok;

Text group; How to address all the elements to bring them to the center but maintaining the specified order;

Webform; How to address all the elements to bring them to the center but maintaining it's webform order assuming I can't (or don't want/need to) access HTML;

I'm already confused after so many tests that I may have unnecessary code below. Thanks all for your help. Tried with relative position, without it, absolute doesn't work since every element it's aligned on top of each other! Etc..Etc..Etc..

SO below class names from the specified elements:

- Juicebox gallery: "viewimagefield"
- Text Group:

  - Article Title:"viewtitlelabel" and "viewtitlefield"
  - Article Reference: "viewreflabel" and "viewrefrield"
  - Article Description: "viewdescriptionfield"
  - Article Price: "viewpricelabel" and "viewpricefield"
- Webform class="viewform":
  -First and Last Name :"prodformname"

  - email: "prodformemail"
  - phone: "prodformphone"
  - message: "prodformmessage"
  - send: "prodformbutton"

```
.viewproducts ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .views-row{
  float: left;
  height:50% !important;
  margin: ;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewimagefield{
  float: left;
  width:40% !important;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewtitlelabel,.viewproducts .view-content .viewtitlefield{
  position: relative;
  top:50% !important;
  left:50% !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewreflabel,.viewproducts .view-content .viewreffield{
  position: relative;
  top:45% !important;
  left:40% !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewdescriptionfield{
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 1%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewpricelabel,.viewproducts .view-content .viewpricefield{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.viewproducts .view-content .viewform{
  top:18% !important;
  left:20% !important;
}
.juicebox-container{
  position: relative !important;
  float: left !important;
  left: 1% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.prodformname, .prodformemail, .prodformphone, .prodformmessage, .prodformabout, .prodformbutton{
  position: relative !important;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left !important;
  top: 1% !important;
  left: 70% !important;
  width: 30% !important;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

The output is the Gallery on the left, Text on center but disaligned and some behind the gallery. Form below both and elements inline, below, etc. I can't understand a specific order here :(
Just an Idea of whats happening in the pic below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEqva.jpg)

here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcosv/ta4kcq7p/18) There's lots of info in the HTML (please be aware that I don't want to change html since i'm working with the Drupal framework and not html coding directly)

Comment: Create a full jsfiddle example

Comment: Hey @StefanBob just did the fiddle, please check https://jsfiddle.net/marcosv/ta4kcq7p/18

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That fiddle and your website code is a mess! I'm out... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @StefanBob, the code is a mess because is the automatic code generated by drupal framework. While working with it you are supposed to use the framework instead of working on html directly. I simply copied the whole html code of the page! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the Bootstrap grid system:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"> 
        //Left section 
        </div> 

        <div class="col-4">
        //Center section 
        </div> 

        <div class="col-4">
        //Right section 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

This will give you equal width sections in the same row.

I suggest you take a look at [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

You can probably achieve similar results by applying `float:left;` to each div using CSS

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the answer. But in order to do so. I would have to access html and like I described that's the last option! Nevertheless, I will look into it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried applying float:left; to each div? If you can attach a fiddle with what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks mate. Yes I applied the float. I will try to to see if I can put up a fiddle . CHeers.

Comment: Hey Robert, here the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/marcosv/ta4kcq7p/18

There's lots of info in the HTML (please be aware that I don't want to change html since i'm working with the Drupal framework and not html coding directly)

Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: The fiddle is a bit messy and some elements don't have proper id's/classes so its hard to find selectors for them especially without changing the HTML. Update your question with the fiddle someone may come with a more appropriate answer. I advise you practice HTML to feel more comfortable in situations like these. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I know some html, but I don't work on it since with drupal you should use the framework and reduce direct html as much as possible, so I just copied the whole html from the page generated by drupal. Furthermore, I don't know how to access the html files (now twigs if I'm not mistaken) through a editor (I use atom). Already looked through the whole project folder and can't find the html that contains the exact code of my page! Thanks anyway